# SQL Error: The Insert Statement Conflicted with the Foreign Key constraint

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foreign-keys, sql

I knew this was a problem I would run into and I'm just not sure how to solve it. I have two tables with the following structures:

```
dbo.File
FileID            int
Title             nvarchar(50)
ISBN              nvarchar(50)
UploadDate        datetime
UserName          nvarchar(50)

dbo.Cover
CoverID           int
CoverFileContent  varbinary(max)
CoverMimeType     nvarchar(50)
CoverFileName     nvarchar(50)
FileID            int
```

The file table has a one to many relationship with the cover table, and FileID in the Cover table references FileID in the File table.

So I also have an MVC application. In this application, on one screen I insert the File Data, then in the following screen I upload a file, and insert this into the cover table, however I get the following error:

> InnerException    {"The INSERT statement
>   conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint \"FK_Cover_File\". The
>   conflict occurred in database
>   \"SampleAppDB\", table \"dbo.File\",
>   column 'FileID'.\r\nThe statement has
>   been terminated."}    System.Exception
>   {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

I know what it means, I've just gone blank as to how I actually perform this insert statement to correspond with the File table. Currently, I'm not inserting anything into the FileID foreign key in the Cover table because I'm not sure how to go about it. Here is a snippet from the Cover controller where the upload of the cover file occurs:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateCover(FormCollection formvalues)
{
    Cover cover = new Cover();

    cover.CoverMimeType = Request.Files["CoverUpload"].ContentType;
    Stream fileStream = Request.Files["CoverUpload"].InputStream;
    cover.CoverFileName = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files["CoverUpload"].FileName);
    int fileLength = Request.Files["CoverUpload"].ContentLength;
    cover.CoverFileContent = new byte[fileLength];
    fileStream.Read(cover.CoverFileContent, 0, fileLength);

    filerepository.AddCoverData(cover);

    filerepository.Save();

    return View(cover);
}
```

any advice on how to handle this problem would be greatly appreciated, if anyone needs me to post more info too, just ask.

As requested: filerepository.cs

```
private SampleAppDBEntities entities = new SampleAppDBEntities();

        public void AddCoverData(Cover cover)
        {
            entities.Covers.AddObject(cover);
        }
```

Comment: The db-related code within your filerepository object definition would help.  Is this linq-to-sql, nhibernate, straight ado.net, other?

Comment: @Tahbaza, I have updated my post with a snippet from filerepository.cs. I'm using ado.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the FileID passed within your FormCollection values as an hidden param
and then have a Cover controller action that initialize it.

For example:

From the File detail page add a link to create a Cover

```
<a href="#" rel='<%= Url.Content("~/Cover/AddCover/FILEID_HERE") %>'>Add cover</a>
```

then you can have a get action on the Cover controller that simply initialize the cover FileID and return the AddCover view

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddCover(int id) {
    CoverModel cm = new CoverModel();
    cm.FileId = id;
    return View("AddCover", cm);
}
```

Finally within your Cover View, that should be typed to the CoverModel simply add the FileID as an hidden field so you can have it posted with the rest of your form data.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("AddCover", "Cover", FormMethod.Post, new {} ))  { %>
    <%= Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FileID) %>

    //Place your cover form fields here

<% } %>
```

One effect of using this pattern is that you can take advantage of using the default model binder features of MVC and have a post action like this one instead of using the FormCollection class:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddCover( CoverModel model ) {
   //Validate your data and tehn add to database
}
```

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, thanks for the reply! I have followed all your advice, except for: CoverModel cm = new CoverModel(id);. I could not add the variable id as I got the following message: "'SampleApp.Models.Cover' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments"...I have added "cover.FileID = int.Parse(Request.Form["FileID"]);" to the POST CreateCover ActionResult however when I click submit/upload I get the same error re. foreign keys as per my original post. Any ideas?

Comment: also, @Lorenzo, Instead of using a link as per your example, I have inserted this line of code into my POST createFile ActionResult: "return RedirectToAction("CreateCover", "Cover", new { id = file.FileID });"..This brings me to the CreateCover page with the id in the URL which seems about right so far.

Comment: sorry to be spamming you, I've sorted out that particular problem, I changed the line in the form to "<%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.File.FileID) %>"...however now I am receiving an error to say that it is null.

Comment: @TaraWalsh: Ok for second comment. In relation to the first one I would add the `cover.FileID = int.Parse(Request.Form["xxx"]);` to the GET also. You have to be sure that the FileID is already initialized when first showing the cover view. Also, if you dont want to use the default Model Binder you have to substitute the `xxx` before specified with the variable name that you are using in your route setup. Check the Global.asax inside your route registration code and you'll find something like this `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"`> this means that the third parameter will be named `id`

Comment: @TaraWalsh: you are getting null value because you have to initialize it in the get action. see my previous comment for the explanation.

Comment: @Lorenzo, that is perfect. Working like a dream. Thank you :)

Comment: @TaraWalsh, you're welcome. One latest advice: use the Model Binder capabilities: you'll love it and it will save from most of the annoying work :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to post the fileId associated to this cover to the controller action:

```
cover.File = filerepository.GetFile(fileId);
```